# A notion of fibration on bisimplicial sets

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, fibration

[I am not trained in this stuff, but have an outside research interest, so sorry if this question is standard.]

I am interested in notions of fibrations, or fibrant objects, in bisimplicial sets.  In particular, the following version seems fairly natural and useful for my purposes, but I can't figure out if it coincides with any of the other notions.

For simplicity I'll stick with defining fibrant objects; the generalization to fibrations should be a detail.

**Definition**: Let $X$ be a bisimplicial set, thought of as a simplicial object in the category of simplicial sets.  So $\operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda^n_k, X)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(\Delta^n,X)$ are naturally simplicial sets (the latter by definition, the former using some sort of diagram), and there is a natural morphism of simplicial sets $\operatorname{Hom}(\Delta^n,X) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda^n_k, X)$ by restriction.  Say $X$ is fibrant if this morphism is a Kan fibration, for all $n$ and $k$.

I believe this is equivalent to the following symmetric criterion.

**Proposition**: $X$ is fibrant if and only if the following holds.  Let $\Lambda^{n,m}_{k,\ell}$ be the bisimplicial set obtained by deleting $\Delta^n_k \widetilde{\times} \Delta^m_\ell$ from $\Delta^n \widetilde{\times} \Delta^m$, where $\Delta^n_i$ denotes the $i$-th codimension one face of $\Delta^n$.  Then we have completion of all $\Lambda^{n,m}_{k,\ell}$-horns in $X$; i.e., $\operatorname{Hom}(\Delta^{n,m}, X) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda^{n,m}_{k,\ell}, X)$ is surjective.

Note $\Lambda^{n,m}_{k,\ell}$ is not the same thing as $\Lambda^n_k \widetilde{\times} \Lambda^m_\ell$.  It is what you get by replacing every face of the $n$-horn $\Lambda^n_k$ with a $\Delta^m$ and the missing face with a $\Lambda^m_\ell$.

The case $n=m=1$ is instructive here.  A $\Lambda^{1,1}_{1,1}$ consists of $\{0,1\} \widetilde{\times}\{0,1\}$ with $\{1\} \widetilde{\times} \{1\}$ removed; i.e., to bi-simplices $\{0\} \widetilde{\times} \{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1\} \widetilde{\times} \{0\}$ which are compatible at $\{0\} \widetilde{\times} \{0\}$.  The statement is that such a configuration in $X$ can be extended to a $(1,1)$-simplex.

Of the three model structures discussed in [1, IV], this notion of fibration seems to be weaker than the diagonal one:

> A horn can be viewed as the part of boundary $\partial \Delta^{p,q}$ of a bisimplex $\Delta^{p,q}$ that results from removing a single cell of maximal total degree. [2]

As I understand it, it is stronger than the Bousfield–Kan model structure fibration, or (given that that notion seems not to be symmetric in the indices) what you get by insisting on a Bousfield–Kan fibration in "both directions".  See [1, IV.3.1].

I have no clear idea what the Reedy model structure is doing [1, IV.3.2] but superficially it seems different and/or more complicated.

So:

**Question**: is this equivalent to any of these three standard notions?  If not, does it have another name or has it been studied?

It seems too natural not to have been, but either I'm misunderstanding or my searches have drawn a blank.

[1] *Goerss, Paul G.; Jardine, John F.*, Simplicial homotopy theory, Progress in Mathematics (Boston, Mass.). 174. Basel: Birkhäuser. xv, 510 p. (1999). [ZBL0949.55001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0949.55001).

[2] *Jardine, J. F.*, [**Diagonal model structures**](http://www.emis.de/journals/TAC/volumes/28/10/28-10abs.html), Theory Appl. Categ. 28, 250-268 (2013). [ZBL1273.18027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1273.18027).

Comment: If you replace $\mathrm{Hom}(\Lambda^n_k,X)$ with $\mathrm{Hom}(\partial \Delta^n,X)$, then you get precisely the notion of a Reedy fibrant bisimplicial set since $\mathrm{Hom}(\partial \Delta^n,X)$ is the matching object of $X$.

Comment: @ValeryIsaev: interesting, thanks! I have to say I haven't really tried to get my head around that stuff.  In my $(1,1)$ example, it seems like this is saying that if you have bisimplices $\{0\} \widetilde{\times} \{0,1\}$,$\{1\} \widetilde{\times} \{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1\} \widetilde{\times} \{0\}$ that are compatible at shared vertices, you can complete to a $(1,1)$-bisimplex, which by coincidence seems to be agree with a diagonal fibration condition.  Is that right?  Either way it seems definitely different.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the diagonal model structure, but it seems that it has strictly less fibrations than the Reedy model structure. Diagonal fibrations must also satisfy a condition symmetric to the one you mentioned.